# Pagination on bootstrap cards

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using bootstrap cards on my page and they will be displayed with PHP from MySQL database. I'd like to add pagination, so I can display 20 cards at once. I've found pagination.js script, but I can't make it work and don't understand why.

This is one of my cards with pure HTML at the moment. For example, I have 30 of these and I'd like to display only 20 of them at once.

```
                    <div class="card" id="motor-cards">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/motor.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="short-data">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Yamaha example</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">11987235 $</h6>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="example"><br>2001</i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-road text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Kilométeróra állása"><br>15000km</i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="example"><br>100cm³</i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-id-card text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="example"><br>A2</i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailsModal">Details</a>
                            <div class="card-footer-icons">
                                <i class="fas fa-warehouse fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Garagehelyezés"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-share-alt fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share" style="padding-left: 5px;"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And this is the pagniation's html, that I should add to my code, but don't understand where. If I put it above my "card" class, then nothing happens.

```
<div id="data-container"></div>
<div id="pagination-container"></div>
```

and the jquery:

```
            $('#pagination-container').pagination({
                dataSource: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
                pageSize: 10,
                callback: function(data, pagination) {
                    // template method of yourself
                    var html = template(data);
                    $('#data-container').html(html);
                }
            })
```

Comment: Whats your backend language (php, ruby, etc)?

Comment: It will be php. But at the moment, I'm using pure html.

Comment: Ok. Then your backend must determine the number of "pages". This could be on php rendering "hard coded". Your front end needs to pass a "range" which could be a page number. I'd recommend reloading the "html/dom" page with a `$_GET["page"]` in place or similar.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's not possible to make it now, without the backend?

Comment: You can do it without a backend. Just means all data will have to be on front-end. Its possible without a backend.

Comment: All data is on front-end now, but can't make it work. Could you show it on my code please?

Comment: Not knowing what your data is, it might be easier to do it "vanilla" without a plugin. Or regular jQuery

Comment: My data are the cards I pasted in the question. I have for example 30 of them, but I just want to display 20 at once.

Comment: Unless these "cards" pull other resources like photos, why not pull them all at once? Am asking this question from perspective of a mobile user.

Comment: Of course each cards have own image and text, but it's just an example

Comment: I cant realistically debug a jQuery plugin. I should have said that first.

Comment: I'd be absolutely satisfied with a vanilla js, I just couldn't find any.

Comment: You could have all "cards" come in, then on "scroll" render images.

Comment: For pagination to work you need data. Here you specified the dataSource as an array with values 1 - 16. If you want your cards to be paginated you need the datasource for the cards as array. In your case 30 of them I believe and the template function must accept the data and return html. In your case the HTML for one card.

Comment: I really want to use a pagination.

Comment: @MohamedMufeed How do I get the datasource for the cards?

Comment: I will explain in the answer. wait.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination to work you need data. Here you specified the dataSource as an array with values 1 - 16. If you want your cards to be paginated, you need the data source for the cards: as array - in your case, 30 of them - I believe, and the template function must accept the data and return html - in your case, the HTML for one card.

For example, lets assume that your data source is something like this.

```js
var data = [
  { 
    id: 'motor-cards',
    img: {
      src: 'images/motor.jpg',
      desc: 'Card image cap'
    }
    name: 'Yamaha example',
    usd: 123456.00,
    year: 2001,
    km: 15000,
    cm3_per_rev: 100
    size_class: 'A2'
  },
  ...
];
```

then you would have a template function like this

```js
var template = function (vehicle) {
 return (
`<div class="card" id="${vehicle.id}">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="${vehicle.img.src}" alt="${vehicle.img.desc}">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="short-data">
            <h5 class="card-title">${vehicle.name}</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${vehicle.usd} $</h6>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="example"><br>${vehicle.year}</i>
                <i class="fas fa-road text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Kilométeróra állása"><br>${vehicle.km}km</i>
                <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="example"><br>${vehicle.cm3_per_rev}cm³</i>
                <i class="fas fa-id-card text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="example"><br>${vehicle.size_class}</i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailsModal">Details</a>
        <div class="card-footer-icons">
            <i class="fas fa-warehouse fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Garagehelyezés"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-share-alt fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share" style="padding-left: 5px;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
  );
}
```

So you will not have this 30 cards in the html, instead, there will only be the container.

**Full eg**.

```html
<div class="pagination-wrapper">
  <div id="cards-container">
    <!-- cards will be put here by pagination.js -->
  </div>
  <div id="pagination-container">
    <!-- the pagination controls will be put here by pagination.js -->
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var data = [
  { 
    id: 'motor-cards',
    img: {
      src: 'images/motor.jpg',
      desc: 'Card image cap'
    }
    name: 'Yamaha example',
    usd: 123456.00,
    year: 2001,
    km: 15000,
    cm3_per_rev: 100
    size_class: 'A2'
  },
  ... // 30 of similar objects for your cards
];

var template = function (vehicle) {
 return (
`<div class="card" id="${vehicle.id}">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="${vehicle.img.src}" alt="${vehicle.img.desc}">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="short-data">
            <h5 class="card-title">${vehicle.name}</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${vehicle.usd} $</h6>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="example"><br>${vehicle.year}</i>
                <i class="fas fa-road text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Kilométeróra állása"><br>${vehicle.km}km</i>
                <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="example"><br>${vehicle.cm3_per_rev}cm³</i>
                <i class="fas fa-id-card text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="example"><br>${vehicle.size_class}</i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailsModal">Details</a>
        <div class="card-footer-icons">
            <i class="fas fa-warehouse fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Garagehelyezés"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-share-alt fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share" style="padding-left: 5px;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
  );
}

var $cardsContainer = $('#cards-container');
$('#pagination-container').pagination({
  dataSource: data,
  pageSize: 20,
  callback: function(data, pagination) {
    $cardsContainer.html(template(data));
  }
})
</script>
```

Note: You may need to tweak here and there according to your use case.

Comment: Now I see how it should work, the only problem is that each data is undefinied. Any idea why? https://i.postimg.cc/Pr14L01V/image.png

Comment: What do you mean? The link is just full of Adds.

Comment: It should be an image of my card, but it says "undefinied" instead any of data.

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying. Can you explain what and where is this undefined? *it* or *data* does’nt conveys anything

Comment: Each $variable, that should have a value. For example, ${vehicle.id}, ${vehicle.img.src}, ${vehicle.img.desc}, ${vehicle.name} and so on.

Comment: Oh. For that, you will need to check the pagination.js doc. I don’t know about its working. from your developer window try debugging and find what data is actually being passed to the `template` function